# Easy way to make ruby Pathname#join act like File.join and not clobber the receiver's path?

Tags: ruby, filepath

According to the rubydoc, if the argument passed to Pathname#join (or Pathname#+) is absolute, the method receiver's path is completely ignored. Example:

```
Pathname('/home/foo').join '/etc/passwd'
# => #<Pathname:/etc/passwd>
```

but

```
File.join('/home/foo', '/etc/passwd')
# => "/home/foo/etc/passwd"
```

Pathname is usually a pleasure to use, but its join behavior is a real annoyance, and I can't think of when I'd ever want that to happen.

Is there an existing method that acts like File.join? It should operate on a Pathname and a string.

A verbose solution like this is not acceptable:

```
Pathname( File.join(pn, '/etc/passwd') )
```

I may accept monkey patches, but they have to be better than this:

```
class Pathname
  def safe_join(other)
    Pathname.new(File.join(self, other))
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

`File.expand_path` behaves the same way as this, and I'd argue it's the proper behavior.

`File.join` operates in a different way and merely serves to join the elements of the path with the proper separator, where `/`, `\` or even `:` are used depending on the OS.

`File.expand_path` interprets a path specification in the context of another, and allows for relative paths to be handled differently from absolute paths. This is an important distinction, especially for configuration files.

If you're going to make your own method, you might want to give it a different name, like `hard_join` or `concat`.

Comment: +1 for reminding me about expand_path. But it still doesn't do what I need. expand_path only works if I do this: `Pathname('etc/passwd').expand_path('/home/foo')`. Ie, the first path must already be relative.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a regex to strip off any preceding `/`:

```
Pathname('/home/foo').join('/etc/passwd'[/[^\/].+$/])
# => #<Pathname:/home/foo/etc/passwd>
```

Comment: I'm afraid it's more verbose than what I mentioned in my question: `Pathname( File.join(pn, '/etc/passwd') )`

Comment: [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html)

Comment: Loves me some regular expressions. +1 for making me laugh.